# SSLContext mock not behaving as expected

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock, powermockito

I've the following simple class:
    import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;

```
public class AClass {
    public void someMethod() throws Exception {
        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        context.init(null, null, null);
    }
}
```

And its JUnit:
    import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ SSLContext.class })
public class ATest {
    @Test
    public void testSomeMethod() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(SSLContext.class);
        SSLContext context = Mockito.mock(SSLContext.class);
        Mockito.when(context.getInstance("SSL")).thenReturn(context);
        new AClass().someMethod();
    }
}
```

The JUnit fails with the following stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.init(Unknown Source)
    at random.AClass.someMethod(AClass.java:8)
    at random.ATest.testSomeMethod(ATest.java:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:68)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:316)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:89)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:97)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:300)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:131)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.access$100(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:59)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner$TestExecutorStatement.evaluate(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:147)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.evaluateStatement(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:107)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:288)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:87)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:50)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:208)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:147)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:121)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:123)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:121)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

The stack trace points to the line with `context.init(null, null, null);` having a null pointer. However when I debug (in Eclipse), I can clearly see that the value of the `context` variable is a `Mock for SSLContext, hashCode: 1857173583`. If a mock, then a void method like `init()` shouldn't do anything. So, why is it throwing a `NullPointerException`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLContext.html#init-javax.net.ssl.KeyManager:A-javax.net.ssl.TrustManager:A-java.security.SecureRandom-) and decompiled signature for the `init` method which throws the `NPE`, it shows as **final**, which basic [Mockito.mock() can not handle](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/FAQ#what-are-the-limitations-of-mockito).

[image: Final method]

On the other hand, the javadoc for `PowerMockito.mock()` reads:

> [org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito](http://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.powermock/powermock-api-mockito/1.6.2)
>
> public static  T mock(Class type)
> Creates a mock object that supports mocking of final and native methods.
> Type Parameters:
>     T - the type of the mock object
> Parameters:
>     type - the type of the mock object
> Returns:
>     the mock object.

So, changing a bit your test should make it work:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({SSLContext.class})
public class ATest {
    @Test
    public void testSomeMethod() throws Exception {
        // create the mock to return by getInstance()
        SSLContext context = PowerMockito.mock(SSLContext.class);

        // mock the static method getInstance() to return above created mock context
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(SSLContext.class);
        Mockito.when(SSLContext.getInstance("SSL")).thenReturn(context);

        // invoke the object under test
        new AClass().someMethod();

        //TODO - add verifications / assertions
    }
}
```

---

**Update:**

Since you're running the test with the `PowerMockRunner`, you can also replace

```
SSLContext context = PowerMockito.mock(SSLContext.class);
```

with a field

```
@Mock
private SSLContext context;
```

which will also be handled by PowerMock (or use `MockitoJUnitRunner` if you just need basic mockito)

Comment: Always thought `PowerMockito.mock()` & `Mockito.mock()` were the same. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @Vineet no problem, indeed, they're [similar](http://i.imgur.com/pIvKZxD.gif), with powermock adding some more features on top of mockito. Also I've updated the answer with a second approach.

Comment: @Morfic - This line `Mockito.when(SSLContext.getInstance("SSL")).thenReturn(context);` doesn't works in my case and gives an error `org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException: Argument should be a mock, but is: class java.lang.Class`. Any pointers please ?

Comment: @Pra_A make sure you annotate your class with `@RunWith` & `@PrepareForTest` and make sure you call `mockStatic` before defining the behaviour, jus like in the sample above.

Comment: @PAA Are you using TestNG?